# Can I add an entry to Dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

Is it possible to add an entry to the bundled Japanese-English dictionary?

I'm using Dictionary version 2.2 (155) on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: the dictionary files OS X’ Dictionary app uses are read-only, and Dictionary.app does not support annotations. You can [create new dictionaries](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/prepare/prepare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006152-CH3-SW7) (though that is not a trivial task), but not modify the existing ones.